# Dataframe partitions are changing during the running

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've noticed the number of partition of the dataframes in my program changes. I mean, I would like to run the program using an specific number of partition, let's say: `256`. The thing is, when appears an `union`, the resultant dataframe sums  up the number of partitions of the dataframes involved in the union. For instance, the initial dataframes have `256` partitions, and the resultant dataframe will have `512`.

I don't know how important is try to keep the `256` partition across all the execution. Also, I can't figure out if performing an another new `union` between the df with `512` partitions and another one with `256`, could affect to something, or if I should apply `repartition` before do the `union`?

I hope to be clear, for further information, please let me know

Comment: Which spark version are you working upon? This behavior with UNION was corrected with Spark 1.3 version.

Comment: I'm using Spark 2.2.0

Comment: any specific reason why you want to give specific number ? This might work small portion of data & If you data is very huge data you might be endign up with heap space exceptions & also you are limiting parallel threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not be concerned about the increased number of partitions unless it is causing a performance issue. If you wanted to recrease the number of partitions after the union, you should use dataframe.coalesce(256) instead of dataframe.repartition(256) as coalesce will be more efficient with a partial shuffle instead if a full shuffle.my advice is to test the performance with and without changing the partitions and see which performs best.